# Can Potential energy be the same as instantaneous kinetic energy?

Tags: kinematics

I often wonder about kinetic energy and potential energy. In physics, if a rock is on top of a hill, it has potential energy or kinetic energy that doesn't exist yet. Instead, is it safe to think of potential energy as instantaneous kinetic energy?  If we were to graph it as kinetic energy over time, it would be a single point (flat line?) and when the rock tumbles down the hill the kinetic energy changes as it approaches the bottom of the hill? Thus, at an infinitesimal point in time, potential energy and kinetic energy are the same?

Comment: In your question, How the kinetic energy decreases as the rock tumbles down  ?

Comment: Hmm.  Eventually the energy will run out as it reaches the bottom?

Comment: The energy will always be conserved as long as there are no non-conservative forces involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential energy is the property of space. Where you put $E_p=0$ is entirely up to you. Kinetic energy is a property of a moving object, you know this from the formulae
$$E_k=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$
So, if an object is sitting/resting at the top of the hill and you have chosen the ground to be
$E_p=0$,
the object has $0$ kinetic energy because it is not moving. However, because it has the "potential" to move, it's potential energy is $$E_p=mgh$$
where $m$ is the mass of the object, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration, and $h$ is the height from the ground ($E_p$=0).
You can find more here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pegrav.html
[image]

This image describes how the energies would behave in a scenario which you described (falling rock).

Comment: So where the two curves intersect, they are the same.

Comment: What  chemical, nuclear or other types of stored energy?  The energies tored are not related to their positionl  What terminology is used for this type pf stored energy?

Comment: Chemical potential energy, mechanical potential energy, electric potential energy, magnetic potential energy, elastic potential energy.    

A chemical bond can be thought of as an attractive force between atoms.
Because of this, atoms and molecules can have chemical potential energy...potential energy stored in chemical bonds

Comment: How can this be if the position of an electron is uncertain?

Comment: It is an abstract term, you are not trying to pinpoint an electron in movement, but you are fixating it to some point in space (or proton if it is a positive charge)